# Focus point of interest and exposure point of interest are mutually exclusive

Tags: ios, camera, focus

This Apple [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html) contains the information below.

> Note: Focus point of interest and exposure point of interest are mutually exclusive, as are focus mode and exposure mode."

I understand what is focus point of interest and exposure point of interest, but can't do the relationship between the two. Why are they mutually exclusive? Can't they have the same point at the same time?

Despite my lack of knowledge about camera, I'd like to know about the relationship.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the apple documentation mentioned "mutually exclusive", it means that if you set one of the point to some point, the other point setting wont get effected.
Their mutually exclusion word is to specify that both functionality are not related, you have the right to change them independently. You can experiment by setting same single point as focus point and exposure point of interest at the same time.You will observe both will function properly according to point set.
So no need to worry, go on and set point whatever you like. 
Hope this helps.